# CGAL's Lazy_exact_nt

Tags: c++, cgal

I use CGAL's Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel so that the number
type K::FT is CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt. Two questions arise:

1. Is there a way to check if K::FT is internally just a double or a GMPQ value?

Note, one can ask (val==to_double(val)) but if true then val may still have a GMPQ under the hood.

2. Is there a way to find out if a certain K::FT instance depends on a DAG?

EDIT: Thank's to the comments below I have come up with a solution that works for simple numbers and for results of operations. But I can't cast cartesian coordinates returned for example by Point_3::x():

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel K;
union LazyTool
{
    LazyTool(const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>* a_):a(a_){}
    LazyTool(const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>& a_):a(&a_){}

    class AccessLazy:public CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>
    {
    public:
        Self_rep* getPtr() const {return (Self_rep*) PTR;}
    };

    template<class T> bool canCast() const
    {
        return (dynamic_cast<T*>(b->getPtr()) != NULL);
    }

    std::string getInfo() const
    {
        if(b->getPtr()==NULL) return "T_INVALID";
        typedef const CGAL::Lazy_exact_Cst<CGAL::Gmpq,double> T_DOUBLE;
        typedef const CGAL::Lazy_exact_Cst<CGAL::Gmpq,int> T_INT;
        typedef const CGAL::Lazy_exact_Ex_Cst<CGAL::Gmpq> T_GMPQ;
        typedef const CGAL::Lazy_exact_unary<CGAL::Gmpq> T_UNARY_OPERATION;
        typedef const CGAL::Lazy_exact_binary<CGAL::Gmpq> T_BINARY_OPERATION;
        if(canCast<T_DOUBLE>()) return "T_DOUBLE";
        if(canCast<T_INT>()) return "T_INT";
        if(canCast<T_GMPQ>()) return "T_GMPQ";
        if(canCast<T_UNARY_OPERATION>()) return "T_UNARY_OPERATION";
        if(canCast<T_BINARY_OPERATION>()) return "T_BINARY_OPERATION";
        return "T_UNKNOWN";
    }
    bool isLazy() const
    {
        return b->getPtr()->is_lazy();
    }
    const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>* a;
    const AccessLazy* b;
};

int main(int,char** )
{
    typedef K::FT dbl;

    dbl a(1);
    dbl b(1.0);
    dbl c(std::string("1/10"));
    dbl d(abs(c));
    dbl e(b+c);
    Point_3 p(a,a,a);
    dbl x(p.x());

    cout<<"a="<<LazyTool(a).getInfo()<<endl;
    cout<<"b="<<LazyTool(b).getInfo()<<endl;
    cout<<"c="<<LazyTool(c).getInfo()<<endl;
    cout<<"d="<<LazyTool(d).getInfo()<<endl;
    cout<<"e="<<LazyTool(e).getInfo()<<endl;
    cout<<"x="<<LazyTool(x).getInfo()<<endl;
}
```

The result is

```
a=T_INT
b=T_DOUBLE
c=T_GMPQ
d=T_UNARY_OPERATION
e=T_BINARY_OPERATION
x=T_UNKNOWN
```

I have tried to find out the type returned by Point_3::x() but Point_3::x() uses a Functor Compute_x_3 which seems to return just an Interval_nt\ even for exact values (which does not make sense - although it works obviously but I do not understand the magic behind the scenes).

Q: To which type do I need to cast x?

EDIT2: This function decouples possibly lazy values (using fit_in_double(..) would probably be more efficient):

```
typedef K::FT dbl;
void decouple(const dbl& val,dbl& decoupled)
{
    // Representable as a double value? Then reconstruct from double
    double dval(to_double(val));
    if(dval==val)
    {
        decoupled=dval;
        return;
    }

    // Otherwise reconstruct from string
    stringstream ss;
    ss<<val.exact();
    decoupled=dbl(ss.str());
}
```

Comment: CGAL::depth(number) might say something. We generally use fit_in_double, which says if the number is equal to a double, often a more useful information that knowing what is under the hood.

Comment: Otherwise, completely unsupported, you can look at Lazy.h, Lazy_exact_nt.h and Handle.h for ways to extract PTR from the Handle in Lazy_exact_nt, and then try to dynamic_cast to Lazy_exact_Cst to check if it is a bignum constant. (Note that depending on options, it may not always be Gmpq that is used)

Comment: @MarcGlisse Thank you for your helpful comment. Deeply nested templates and inheritance make the source hard to read. In my understanding the variable Lazy_rep::et is either NULL or it holds a pointer to CGAL::Gmpq and a DAG can only exist when Lazy_rep::et==NULL. But where is the DAG stored?

Comment: The DAG is stored in the Handle that Lazy derives from.

Comment: @MarcGlisse thank you again. I have come up with a solution (see above) but can't cast cartesian coordinates returned by a point.

Comment: You were asking for cases where internally it is just wrapping a double/Gmpq, and that's not the case for p.x(), which returns a DAG, with an interval for that value, and instructions saying that if it is asked for the exact value, it will recursively ask for the exact value of p and apply Compute_x_3 (from the basic exact kernel, not from the interval kernel) to it. p itself also has a DAG based on Construct_point_3 and a. So it isn't clear to me what you are trying to achieve now. You may want to check Lazy_construction_nt in CGAL/Lazy.h.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Sorry, I missed to clarify my intentions: I want to compute (for example) intersections of triangles with multiple threads. The Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel is not threadsafe but conflicts are avoided when the threads operate on chunks with disjoint bounding boxes. The problem is that the corners of the Triangle_3 objects may consist of coordinates that depend on a DAG and the numbers in the DAG may be shared with geometric objects _outside_ the bounding box. Inefficient solution: Call exact() on all numbers. Desired solution: Find out if a number has a DAG.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for objects for which `!is_lazy()`, and you are also willing to accept those that are lazy but where update_exact does not clean up (like those constructed from an int) so it is thread-safe to look through them. But I expect you won't find that many objects without a DAG... `p.x()` returns a number with a DAG, referencing operation `Compute_x_3` and object `p`.

Comment: Yes, threads working on disjoint bounding boxes of non-lazy objects are safe anyway while lazy numbers are dangerous because they may depend on other numbers. Finding out if they do is actually the problem and I thought that this is the same as looking for a DAG. Well, meantime I have come up with a solution that decouples values. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ah, you were going to walk through the whole DAG to check the bounding box of all the points that are involved? That could work, but it may get expensive...

Comment: No, instead I decouple all coordinates before I enter multithreading. This is very fast and it guarantees that no dangerous link between the numbers remains. I have edited the post above right now to add the decouple() function.

Comment: There are more efficient ways to unshare than going through a string. If you enable GMPXX (replaces Gmpq with mpq_class), `decoupled=val.exact()` seems sufficient. Otherwise, `decoupled=Gmpq(val.exact().mpq())`. Yes, fit_in_double seems easier for the first part.